# How to display this as percent with 3 decimals in Java?

Tags: java

```
  float f = 0.564f;
  System.out.println(String.format("Percent: %.3f%%", f));
```

This displays as below:

```
Percent: 0.564%
```

I want to display as 56.4% and I want to use String.format(). How to change this to achieve the effect?

Comment: Just multiply f with 100

Comment: simply `100*f`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this with 1 decimal:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Percent: %.1f%%", (f*100)));
```

If you want to have it with 3 decimals

```
System.out.println(String.format("Percent: %.3f%%", (f*100)));
```

And so on

Comment: I would keep `%.3f` since the title mention a percent with 3 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to calculate the percentage first from the proportion:

```
String.format("Percent: %.1f%%", 100 * f)
```

Note that your expected output only has 1 decimal. 3 decimals would display as
`56.400%`. If you want that, don't change your format string.

Comment: I would keep `%.3f` since the title mention a percent with 3 decimals.

Comment: @AxelH I don't think our discussion provides any form of useful information, so I deleted my comments.